# PHP setcookie() fails ( sometimes ) on iPhone safari

Tags: php, cookies, safari

I have a strange problem with setcookie(). It works and is in production, but sometimes it fails and only on iPhone. If we clear all cookies, everything is fine again. It is not a problem on all iPhones and I have not been able to reproduce the problem. But once in a while, a customer will report the problem. As far as I can tell, it's only on safari on iPhone.

Does anyone know how to fix this or can lead me in the right direction?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->removeUserCookie();
}

private function setUserCookie($user): void
{
    $encoded_user = base64_encode(json_encode($user));
    $expires = time() + 60 * 60 * 24;
    setcookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, $encoded_user, $expires, '/', $this->getDomain());
}

public function removeUserCookie(): void
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE[self::COOKIE_NAME])) {
        unset($_COOKIE[self::COOKIE_NAME]);
    }
    setcookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, null, time() - 3600, '/', $this->getDomain());
}

private function getDomain(): string
{
    //return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $exploded_domain = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $domain = implode('.', array_slice($exploded_domain, -2, 2));
    return $domain;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are we talking about a 3rd-party cookie here? Apple has become quite restrictive regarding those lately in Safari, in an attempt to better protect user privacy.

Comment: No, this is me, trying to set a cookie, on my domain.